# why chef_gem recipe works from chef-solo and not through vagrant

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo, cookbook

Resources **chef_gem** works with `chef-solo` but not with `vagrant up`

*myapp/Vagrantfile*

```js
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = "my-hostname"
  config.vm.box = "ubn1204-chef-gemsources-i386"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "33.33.33.10"
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 120
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.json = {
      :mysql => {
        :server_root_password => 'rootpass',
        :server_debian_password => 'debpass',
        :server_repl_password => 'replpass'
      }
    }
    chef.run_list = [
      "recipe[myface::mysql_gem]"
    ]
  end
end
```

*myapp/recipes/mysql_gem.rb*

```js
%w{mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev make}.each do |pack|
  package pack do
    action :nothing
  end.run_action(:install)
end
g = chef_gem "mysql" do
  action :nothing
end
g.run_action(:install)
```

when execute `vagrant up` I get the following error

```
[2014-01-22T15:21:06+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-01-22T15:21:07+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.8.2 ***
[2014-01-22T15:21:07+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1162
[2014-01-22T15:21:09+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[myface::mysql_gem]"] from JSON
[2014-01-22T15:21:09+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[myface::mysql_gem]]
[2014-01-22T15:21:09+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [myface::mysql_gem]
[2014-01-22T15:21:09+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for myface-berkshelf
[2014-01-22T15:21:09+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-01-22T15:21:09+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-01-22T15:22:54+00:00] WARN:  failed to find gem mysql (>= 0) from [http://rubygems.org/]
[2014-01-22T15:22:54+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-01-22T15:22:54+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-01-22T15:22:54+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-01-22T15:22:54+00:00] ERROR: chef_gem[mysql] (myface::mysql_gem line 6) had an error: ArgumentError: Illformed requirement [""]

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'chef_gem[mysql]'
================================================================================


ArgumentError
-------------
Illformed requirement [""]


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/mysql_gem.rb:9:in `from_file'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/mysql_gem.rb

  6: g = chef_gem "mysql" do
  7:   action :nothing
  8: end
  9: g.run_action(:install)


Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/mysql_gem.rb:6:in `from_file'

chef_gem("mysql") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
  action [:nothing]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  package_name "mysql"
  cookbook_name :myface
  recipe_name "mysql_gem"
end




================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/mysql_gem.rb
================================================================================


ArgumentError
-------------
chef_gem[mysql] (myface::mysql_gem line 6) had an error: ArgumentError: Illformed requirement [""]


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/mysql_gem.rb:9:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/mysql_gem.rb:

  2:    package pack do
  3:      action :nothing
  4:    end.run_action(:install)
  5:  end
  6:  g = chef_gem "mysql" do
  7:    action :nothing
  8:  end
  9>> g.run_action(:install) 10:  


[2014-01-22T15:21:06+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-01-22T15:22:54+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

however I go into vagrant VM `vagrant ssh`

execute vagrant$ `sudo chef-solo -c /vagrant/solo.rb -j /vagrant/aux.rb` **it works ok.**

when

*/vagrant/aux.rb*

```js
{
    "mysql": {
    "server_root_password": "rootpass",
    "server_debian_password": "debpass",
    "server_repl_password": "replpass"
},
    "run_list": [ "recipe[myface::mysql_gem]" ]
}
```

and

*/vagrant/solo.rb*

```js
file_cache_path    "/var/chef/cache"
file_backup_path   "/var/chef/backup"
cookbook_path ["/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks"]
log_level :info
verbose_logging    true

encrypted_data_bag_secret "/tmp/encrypted_data_bag_secret"
```

Someone knows why it works ok directly from **chef-solo** and not through **vagrant**?

**Tools versions**

- ruby 1.9.3p392
- virtualbox 4.3.6
- Chef: 11.8.2
- Vagrant 1.3.5 plugin
- vagrant-berkshelf (1.3.7)
- vagrantbox Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: `chef_gem "mysql"` is executed during _compile_ stage. Why do you need to specify `action :nothing` and `run_action :install`?

Comment: @Draco Ater something I saw [here](http://ry4an.org/unblog/post/chef_mysql_database_vagrant/)

Comment: Well, it's either does not change anything or does more harm than good. Have you tried just `chef_gem "mysql"`?

Comment: yes, that started. with the same error, then find what I gave in the question

Answer (score 0):

This is a know Chef bug - [CHEF-3912](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3912)